# How to add individual tags to certain items in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am looping over a list of students and displaying them on the page. Each student has the ability to add a tag to their container, but the problem I am having with my solution is that this is adding to every single students tags, instead of only the student I want it added to. How can i make this add tag function unique to each student?

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState([]);
  const [studentFilter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setStudent(result.students);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, [setStudent]);

 

  const addTag = (e) => {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      setTags([...tags, e.target.value]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        id="name-input"
        placeholder="Search by name"
        type="text"
        className="filter-students"
        onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
      />

      {student
        .filter(
          (name) =>
            name.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter) ||
            name.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter)
        )
        .map((students) => {
          let total = 0;
          for (let i = 0; i < students.grades.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(students.grades[i]);
          }

          const average = total / students.grades.length;

          return (
            <div className="student-container">
              <img className="student-img" src={students.pic} />
              <div className="student-column">
                <p className="student-item">
                  {" "}
                  {students.firstName} {students.lastName}
                </p>
                <p className="student-item">Email: {students.email}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Company: {students.company}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Skill: {students.skill}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Average: {average}%</p>

                
                  
                  {tags.map((tag) => {
                    return <p className="student-tags">{tag}</p>;
                  })}


                  <input
                    onKeyDown={addTag}
                    className="student-tag"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Add a tag"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <button onClick={displayScores} className="expand-btn">
                +
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you just store tags globally and display them all for every students.

Here is a way, not a solution, I didn't test anything. Just a proposition of how to do it. I just hope student have `id`.

Change the add tag to tell on which student it must be added. Tags are now object, with studentId and value.

```
 const addTag = (studentId, e) => {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      setTags([...tags, {studentId, value:e.target.value}]);
    }
  };
```

Change the click handler

```
<input
    onKeyDown={addTag.bind(this, student.id)}
    className="student-tag"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Add a tag"
/>
```

Change the display method

```
{tags.filter(t => t.studentId === student.id).map((tag) => {
    return <p className="student-tags">{tag.value}</p>;
})}
```

Comment: Or there is a little type in your code `.map((students) => {` you should write `.map((student) => {` instead, cause there is only one student at a time here.

Comment: Thanks alot, makes perfect sense! Students dont have ids, but an email which is still unique